# Cannot implement tetris move methods

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm writing tetris right now, I have a method that drops figures one by one onto the same position on the screen, that methods starts working after double tapping the screen and it is called in while loop:

```
while (gameState == gamePlaying) {}
```

The problem is that I donn't know how to make my `moveLeft` or `moveRight` methods work by `UISwipeGesture` or even just by using a button, because while dropping method works I'm not able to use any buttons or gestures (if I understand it right)
So how can I create a button which would have higher priorty than the method that works at the moment?!(or how to use `UISwipeGestures` in this situation?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would also suggest using a NSTimer for the scheduling of the game logic. If you simply want to perform an action in a background thread such that the user interface doesn't block you can use for example:

```
-(void)performGameLogic
{
    //Do the game logic
}

-(void)startGame
{
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(performGameLogic) withObject:nil];
}
```

NSTimer variant:

```
@interface Game
{
    NSTimer * timer;
}

-(void)performGameLogic
{
    //Do the game logic
}

-(void)startGame
{
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 0.1 target:self selector:@selector(performGameLogic:) userInfo:nil repeats: YES];
}

@end
```